# How to decrypt the laravel encryped on C#?

Tags: c#, laravel

Hi I have a small project work on laravel &win c#. I have encrypted from laravel as below.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
///
$user->balance = Crypt::encrypt($balance);
```

I can decrypt on laravel as below.

```
$balance = Crypt::decrypt($this->balance);
```

But I do not know how to decrypt using c# with the same algorithm. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: [The docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/encryption#using-the-encrypter) might be a useful starting point: _"All encrypted values are encrypted using OpenSSL and the `AES-256-CBC` cipher."_ Searching for "c# laravel aes-256-cbc" resulted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368840/how-to-encrypt-in-c-sharp-that-is-compatible-with-laravels-encryption/45633123). Note that I have never used Laravel, I just Googled it to be helpful, so I've no idea if this information is correct. Sorry.

Comment: Dear John,Thank you for information.

Comment: Dear Markus Deibel. Any way, thanks.